# Zoom Google Line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I am trying to create a line chart with the Google Visualization API. I want to enable zooming. [Documents](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) say that the 'explorer' option is useful. 
But when I try to use the 'explorer' option, the chart is shown but zoom does not work.

This is my code:

```
function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
var data = new window.google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([new Date(dataValues[i].Year, dataValues[i].Month-1, dataValues[i].Day), dataValues[i].Count]);
}

var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ formatType: 'short' });
formatter_short.format(data, 0);
var options = {
    title: "Time statistics",
    explorer: { maxZoomOut: 8 }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('date'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

How can I resolve this problem and make a line chart zoomable?

Comment: There is a known bug in the API when using the explorer option with a "date" type axis.  The dev team is working on a solution.

Answer (score 40):

Here is How I got the zoom with the `dragToZoom` explorer function

```
explorer: { 
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

the fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/4w626v2s/2/

also by just allowing it to zoom by scrolling

```
explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

the fiddle for scroll to zoom is here https://jsfiddle.net/5h7jxqq8/2/

Comment: Hello this is not working for me..Please help its urgent

Comment: @HarrySharma can you atleast explain how you have used it?

Comment: @HarrySharma looks like zoom is not yet defined for gantt charts

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#methods

Comment: How to zoom and Scroll google Chart on Mobile device or Android Webview? I have tried above option working fine on my Computer browser  but not working on Android Webview ormobile browser, please help me..

Answer (score 17):

This seems to be working now with  [LineChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) AND [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) (even though this one is not documented).

```
var options = {
    explorer: {
        maxZoomOut:2,
        keepInBounds: true
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duJA8/

Comment: Also this works with scatterplots. Also as far as I know this features does NOT work if you have any of the log scaling on the axes.

Comment: Hello this is not working for me..Please help its urgen

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
     drawChart();
     window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
    },
    packages:['corechart']
   });

   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
     ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
     ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
     ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
     ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var options = {
     animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
     },
     height: 600,
     width: window.innerWidth,
     theme: 'material',
     title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="columnchart_material" style="height: 500px; "></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want to set Width and Height according to the Screen. So, you can achieve this by using "innerWidth" and "innerHeight" as shown below:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
     drawChart();
     window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
    },
    packages:['corechart']
   });

   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
     ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
     ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
     ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
     ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var options = {
     animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
     },
     height: window.innerHeight,
     width: window.innerWidth,
     theme: 'material',
     title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="columnchart_material"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Below code will work but you should not use animation on your charts. Remove animation and use only explorer. This is a bug, if animation is applied then zoom will not work.

I spent weeks to figure this out.

```
explorer: {
  keepInBounds: true,
  maxZoomIn: 8.0
}
```

Comment: you spent weeks to figure this out, but the same answer is here since 2014. scroll up.