# Google Chart Pan Zoom Buttons

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, zooming, pan

I'm searching for having zoom and pan buttons on a google chart.
Like [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlIts.png). (Maybe there is no option to have it and i have to dev it myself)
I also wondering how they do to have dynamic Xmin and Xmax. Is this calculated in real time by the client ?

Comment: see the configuration option for `explorer` -- this option doesn't add any buttons but allows the user to zoom and pan...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possiblity to zoom in a google chart. The zooming is done by clicking and dragging the mouse left or right. Panning ist not possible in this version (but you don't need a scroll wheel).

```
explorer: { 
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

If you want to try it look here: https://jsfiddle.net/4w626v2s/2/

---

Another possiblity is the following. Here you need a mouse scroll wheel to zoom into the chart. After zooming you can click and drag to pan within the chart.

```
explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

And here you can test it: https://jsfiddle.net/5h7jxqq8/2/

Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764157/zoom-google-line-chart/36596155#36596155)

Comment: Above both option are not working in android WebView.. please help me how to Zoom & Scroll Chart in android Webview..  @Michael

Comment: If the fiddle didn't work on your Android device it may depend on your browser. Try another browser. Basically it should not matter which operating System you have.

Comment: I don't think it is a browser issue.. because in Mobile browser there is no right click to reset Zoom or drag to zoom **eg:actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']**

Comment: In a touch environment (e. g. mobile phone) a right click can be performed by touching a üoint on the display for more than 1 second ('long click'). That's how a reset should work.

Comment: How to zoom in mobile device?, Zoom is also not working.. @Michael

Comment: I tried it on my mobile phone - it also does not work. May be there is no possibility to do this with google charts. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your Help.. Happy Coding.. @Michael