# Zooming google corechart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I've seen in other posts that googlecharts can be easily zoomed using the option `explore`. 
I've been unsuccessfully trying to zoom this chart with the following characteristics:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'value');
          data.addRows([['2001', 12],['2002', 15],['2003', 16],
                        ['2004', 12],['2005', 15],['2006', 19],
                        ['2007', 12],['2008', 25],['2009', 16],
                        ['2010', 22],['2011', 12],['2012', 13]]);

          var options = {
           title: 'Price Chart',
            explorer: {actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],axis: 'horizontal',keepInBounds: true,maxZoomIn: 4.0},
             legend: { position: 'bottom' }
             };
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
          }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

As shown in the comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764157/zoom-google-line-chart) question, i'm not using the parameter `date` to pass the data, so the bug doesn't come from here.

I'm guessing that the problem comes ethier from `addRows` or `div`.

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rk9cqc7n/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: the `explorer` option only works with a continuous x-axis (number, date values), not with a discrete x-axis (string values)

Comment: Totally right @WhiteHat, I didn't lool carefully on the documentation. I just changed it to new Date as [it is suggested](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes) and now it works. If you put it as an aswer, I can accep it or I will just close the question ;)